# How to Automate publishing App Bundle to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew, android-app-bundle

Actually i has try any tutorial with [GPP](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher#----gradle-play-publisher) for publish bundle to play store, but always stuck in this error when i trying with **./gradlew publishBundle**.

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated

My gradle setup is the same like [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@AndreSand/automate-publishing-app-bundle-or-apk-to-google-play-store-8641f0ba2f64). For anyone use GPP library and success build the bundle, you can write some tips for fix this or for any people has success build the bundle app with other library too.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to run "./gradlew clean" before publishBundle? Your error may be caused by residual files created by gradle during your development process.

Comment: Moreover, your "android/gradle.properties" file must have the following lines at the beginning: "android.useAndroidX=true" and "android.enableJetifier=true"